# Probability regarding sum of throws of 6 dices

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

Six dices are thrown one after another. Find the probability that the sum of the numbers for the six throws lies between 10 and 20.

My attempt: 
Exhaustive number of outputs = $6^6$

Number of ways in which we get the sum of numbers as 10 in 6 throws = Coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the expansion $(x + x^2 +x^3 +x^4 + x^5 + x^6)^6 = \binom{6 + 4 -1}4 = \binom{9}4= 126$

Similarly, we can get the sum as 11 in $ \binom{6 + 5 -1}5 = \binom{10}5 $ ways and we can get the sum as 20 in $ \binom{6 + 14 -1}{14} = \binom{19}{14} $ ways

So required probability = $\frac{\binom{9}4  + \binom{10}5 + ... + \binom{19}{14} }{6^6}$

I am not sure if this procedure is correct. Please confirm.

Comment: Why are you interested in the coefficient of $x^{10}$?

Comment: It is perfectly fine. For a larger number of throws, it might be convenient to invoke the central limit theorem.

Comment: Thank you @JackD'Aurizio for confirming.